# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod.METHODS when I using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, httpurlconnection

```
my post request 

@POST("/users/login-facebook")
@FormUrlEncoded
void loginFaceboook(@Field("token") String accessToken, @Field("fbId") String facebookId, @Field("platform") int platform,

                    Callback<LoginSignupResponse> callback)
```

my gradle

```
   compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
```

also my all post services have an same error

Comment: How to do the same request in squareup.okhttp ?. Can any one Help me?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dependency versions are ancient and incompatible.

For retrofit 1.x the latest is 1.9.0 and with it you want to use latest okhttp 2.x which is currently 2.7.5.

Consider migrating to retrofit 2.x and okhttp 3.x though.

- https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases
- https://github.com/square/okhttp/releases

Comment: i change my gradle     compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'  and i had an error again java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.<init>
                                                                  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:367)

Comment: The urlconnection library version should match your okhttp version.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

put this in gradle:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0'

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/users/login-facebook")
void loginFaceboook(@Field("token") String accessToken, @Field("fbId") String facebookId, @Field("platform") int platform,

                    Callback<LoginSignupResponse> callback)
```

Comment: i had edited the answer please try it. if you get the error please share the Log

Comment: i added okio bot didnt change  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpMethod.METHODS
                                                                    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:550)
                                                                    at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.prepareRequest(UrlConnectionClient.java:50)
                                                                    at

Comment: i update my gradle    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5' and  problem solved , thank you for answers

Answer (score 0):

Try below instead

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'

Also, there is no need to put entries for okhttp or okio in gradle.